# How to clear radio button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a radio button named "Choose" with the options yes and no. If I select any one of the options and click the button labeled "clear", I need to clear the selected option, using javascript. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You don't need to have unique `id` for the elements, you can access them by their `name` attribute:

If you're using `name="Choose"`, then:

### With recent jQuery

```
$('input[name=Choose]').prop('checked',false);
```

### With old jQuery (<1.6)

```
$('input[name=Choose]').attr('checked',false);
```

### or in pure JavaScript

```
var ele = document.getElementsByName("Choose");
for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
    ele[i].checked = false;
```

[Demo for JavaScript](http://jsbin.com/gelar/1)

Comment: Actually, this is what David Andersson suggested.  I guess I missed his comment before I posted.

Comment: +1 Its really working NVRAM.. Thanks and i am choosing this as a my accepted answer. Thanks everyone for your valuable answers.

Comment: in jquery version above 1.6 use $('input[name=Choose]').prop('checked',false);

Answer (score 29):

If you do not intend to use jQuery, you can use simple javascript like this

```
document.querySelector('input[name="Choose"]:checked').checked = false;
```

Only benefit with this is you don't have to use loops for two radio buttons

Answer (score 12):

This should work. Make sure each button has a unique ID.  (Replace Choose_Yes and Choose_No with the IDs of your two radio buttons)

```
document.getElementById("Choose_Yes").checked = false;
document.getElementById("Choose_No").checked = false;
```

An example of how the radio buttons should be named:

```
<input type="radio" name="Choose" id="Choose_Yes" value="1" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="Choose" id="Choose_No" value="2" /> No
```

Comment: If i have one common id means, then how could i proceed?

Comment: You need to change it to separate IDs.  You should not have more than one of the same ID on a page.  You need to use the same Name to make it a radio button group, but the ID has to be unique.

Comment: @i2ijeya I would use a library such as http://jquery.com/ where I could select by class if I wanted to select more radio buttons at once. You could also use document.getElementsByName("Choose").

Comment: While jQuery is great, it does not need to be used for every little bit of JavaScript.  In this case it would just be unnecessary overhead for something that's pretty simple to do in plain JavaScript.

Comment: As David says, you can access by _name_, so _id_ isn't required for this function.  Also, I suspect a typo -- your _value_ is the same for both buttons.

Comment: Even when we have same `id` it is possible to clear selection. See my answer below

Answer (score 5):

An ES6 approach to clearing a group of radio buttons:

```
    Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('input[name="group-name"]:checked'), input => input.checked = false );
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case this got the job done:

```
const chbx = document.getElementsByName("input_name");

for(let i=0; i < chbx.length; i++) {
    chbx[i].checked = false;
}
```

Comment: I'm having an issue with this js code. When you reset a radio groud, whenever I select the same value again, I get an undefined

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't a better alternative be to just add a third button ("neither") that will give the same result as none selected?

Comment: I quote this solution. Radio buttons, as a UI element, are not meant to be reset (ie: none of them checked). They are designed to start with 1 option checked, and the possibility to change it. You may consider to change your radio buttons to a dropdown list: {empty}|Yes|No

Comment: @Filini Windows forms programming has 3-state radio buttons, not sure why they can't be used for the Web.

Comment: @Shawn, are you sure you are not thinking about tri-state checkboxes? Anyway, how does this relate to the possibility to reset a radio button?

Comment: @Filini - sometimes you might need to reset the radio buttons, all unchecked. I faced situation in a Quiz App - when user restarts the quiz, all the options (radio buttons) should be unchecked (created in AngularJS).

Answer (score 0):

```
YES<input type="radio" name="group1" id="sal" value="YES" >

NO<input type="radio" name="group1" id="sal1" value="NO" >

<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('sal').checked=false;document.getElementById('sal1').checked=false">
```

Comment: That won't actually work if NO is checked because javascript will never see the 2nd element with the same ID.

Comment: -1. It's invalid HTML to have multiple elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, no jQuery required:

```
<a href="javascript:clearChecks('group1')">clear</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function clearChecks(radioName) {
    var radio = document.form1[radioName]
    for(x=0;x<radio.length;x++) {
        document.form1[radioName][x].checked = false
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the id of the radio buttons are 'male' and 'female', value reset can be done by using jquery

```
$('input[id=male]').attr('checked',false);
$('input[id=female]').attr('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Somtimes i have to remove attribute checked from inputs type="radio" :

```
let el = document.getElementById('your_input_id');
    el.checked = false;
    el.removeAttribute('checked');
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="btn"> Item1
  <input type="radio" name="btn"> Item2<br>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

This could work..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).