# Set radio to unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have an accordion which is done by checked and unchecked radio buttons. When the page is loaded everything is collapsed however I have no way to achieve this after they have initially been opened. 
I want to be able to fully collapse the accordion again.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMdQdv

```
input[type=radio] + label::after {
 content: "\25BC";
 }
```

Comment: Use a checkbox instead!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear radio button in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554116/how-to-clear-radio-button-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a click event listener to the labels, check if the corresponding input is currently checked, and if so, uncheck it by setting its `checked` property to `false`. You also have to call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent it from being checked again.

```
document.querySelectorAll('label').forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const inputId = event.target.getAttribute('for');
    const input = document.getElementById(inputId);
    if (input.checked) {
      input.checked = false;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
);
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXpVMe).

Answer (score 4):

You should use a checkbox instead:

```
<input id="tab-four" type="checkbox" name="tabs2">
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oEpjdM).

Comment: It sounds like to me the OP wants something that will close when a different option is selected, a checkbox won't do that (without js).

Answer (score 0):

As Michal's answer says, you should use a checkbox instead of a radio button.

For the reason why:

Radio buttons can't be unchecked. Once you select one, you can change which one is selected, but you can't manually uncheck it.

Checkboxes, on the other hand, are a toggle. So they'll work better in your situation.

Comment: Radio buttons can be unchecked with JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, which fundamentally breaks the intended functionality of the element.