# Can you cancel the 'Checked' HTML property for a radio button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

Is it possible to cancel the `checked` HTML property for a radio button using JavaScript?

I have this layout:

```html
<div class="wss_final_delivery">
  <div class="wss_final_delivery_wrap">Would you like to accept final delivery
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="wss_accept_delivery" value="yes">
        Yes
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="wss_accept_delivery" value="no" checked="">
        No
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

This results in the "No" option to be checked by default. I would like none of the options to be checked by default and let the user choose his option. However, I can not change the HTML code. Is it possible to achieve using JavaSricpt?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("[name='wss_accept_delivery']").forEach(function(item){item.checked = false;});`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554116/how-to-clear-radio-button-in-javascript) should provide additional information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear radio button in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554116/how-to-clear-radio-button-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using javascript, like this:

```
 document.querySelectorAll("[name='wss_accept_delivery']").forEach(radio=> {
  radio.checked = false;
  radio.removeAttribute('checked')
 });
```